# Checking service fsockopen()

Tags: php, fsockopen

I'm trying to check service on port 9998. To do so I'm using **fsockopen()** function.

Like this:

```
$host = "1.1.1.1";
$port = "9998";
$checkconn = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
if($checkconn >= 1){
echo 'ok';
} else {
echo "$errstr";
}
```

It always returns **"Connection Timed Out - 110"**, but the port is open and there is service running there.

If I change the port (like 80), it returns successful, but why not on the 9998 port?

Comment: firewall blocking outgoing connections on non-standard ports?

Comment: I don't think so, anyway, how can I check that?

Answer (score 2):

A 1 second connect timeout is not very long.  Network lag can be enough to trigger that even when the host/port is valid.  I would suggest using at least 2.5 - 5 seconds instead.

Also, you should be checking the result of `fsockopen()` for `FALSE` instead of `< 1` to know when it fails.

Try this:

```
$host = "1.1.1.1";
$port = "9998";
$checkconn = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if(!$checkconn){
    echo "($errno) $errstr";
} else {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Comment: I have tried to check for FALSE value before and even higher timeouts (like 10), but it never worked...I always get the same respose "Connection Timed Out"